# SimpleModal autoresize not enitrely correct

Tags: simplemodal

With the following HTML and JS:

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">
    <div class="dialog-title">Dialog Title</div>
    Some text
    <div class="dialog-buttons">
        <button class="uk-button">Button 1</button>
        <button class="uk-button">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button onClick="$('#dialog').modal();">open dialog</button>
```

I get a simplemodal that is not big enough for the contents, with styled buttons using UI-Kit (http://getuikit.com/). The buttons are too wide so are wrapped, making the second button appear outside of the modal.

Any ideas how to get the simplemodal sized correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not got the perfect answer but I do have a working answer, adjust the css.

```
/* Container */
#simplemodal-container {
  height:auto !important;
  width:600px;
  ...
  }
```